# Remove element highlight on tap in Firefox for Android

Tags: android, css, firefox

A button changes its background color to half-transparent gray for a brief moment when it's tapped. I want to disable this behavior or set the color myself.

I wouldn't care much about it if I didn't have both background color and image set: while the color changes, the image stays and it looks ugly.

I've tried :active, :hover, :active:hover, with no success.
-webkit-tap-highlight-color doesn't apply here, as it's not a Webkit browser (but I've tried it anyway...).
It's not a matter of a dotted outline, which I've been able to remove.

Here's some code for reference:

```
<style>
  #that_button {
    background: url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png) 130px .3em no-repeat;
    background-size: auto 1.5em;
    background-color: #66ccff;
    border: none;
    height: 2em;
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>
<button id="that_button">Hello</button>
```

Comment: Do you have any code for us to take a look at?

Comment: I've added an example code.

Comment: What browser on your Android device are you testing on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The highlight style definition is there: https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/f003c386c77a/mobile/android/themes/core/content.css#l309, and it cannot be overridden. The only "solution" then is to use divs or other elements that won't match the selector in the source, since they won't get highlighted (although that won't be a semantic html).

I've been able to contact devs and this is the result: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=936593, so that behavior should be fixed. Sorry for the delay in providing the answer when I've found it.

Comment: What's the status of this from the Mozilla side? Can we change it yet?